# Serialize ArrayList of Users containing bitmaps

Tags: java, android, serialization, bitmap, arraylist

i need to implement a logon activity that maintains a history of logged in users. Each user also has an image (bitmap) attached to it. When a user successfully logs on, i need to update the user history persisted in local storage.

Because of the bitmap i cannot serialize the arraylist containing the users.

Here is the user class code:

```
public class User implements Serializable
{
private String username;
private String systemUserID;
private Date loginDate;
private Bitmap image;
```

How can i implement arraylist serialization to be able to store the arraylist of users? I zipped through the web and found a hint converting the bitmap to a byte array.

How does this work?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always take a giant pause before using the Serializable interface. Using it has a huge potential to come back and bite you in the butt. But I digress. Bitmaps aren't serializable so you're out of luck as far as that goes. That said, there's still a good solution to your problem. Instead of serializing each User object, you just keep track of everything in a [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database. And as far as the bitmap goes, just store it on the SDCard in and you database store the file path to it. SQLite databases are generally how we do persistent storage in android.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented this specific type of logic but here is roughly what you would need to do.

1. Read some serialization docs. For example, [this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javarmi/chapter/ch10.html).
2. Add methods `writeObject( )/readObject( )` to your `User` class.
3. Inside those methods, use [copyPixelsToBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) and [copyPixelsFromBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) to save to/read from NIO [Buffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer.html).
4. Transfer data as needed between `Buffer` and your output/input stream.

Answer (score 0):

If Bitmap is not serializable you have to mark it as transient and provide your own custom serialization for it (implement readObject and writeObject), like writing its content as binary data (or sth more sophisticated).

```
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
      byte[] bitmapInBytes = convertToBytes(bitmap);
      oos.defaultWriteObject();
      oos.writeObject(bitmapInBytes);
 }
```

You can figure out the opposite direction. Keep in mind that (custom) serialization goes by FIFO order what means you should read the data in the same order you wrote it.